# How do I clear a column filter with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I run into problems with existing spreadsheets where users have applied an autofilter and then filtered on some criteria before saving the workbook.  I want to clear these filters preferably using `openpyxl` but cannot seem to figure out how to do it.  Setting them is straight forward.

So what I have tried is to actually just move the autofilter to some other range.  This works in moving the filter away from the affected columns, it does *not* clear the filter though.  It remains in place.

Using the code below, I can set `autofilter`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = "path_to\\filter_test.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active
ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions
wb.save(filename)
```

I then open the spreadsheet and set the filter to some state to filter the data and save the workbook.

I then move the filter:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = "C:\\Users\\paul.nel\\Desktop\\filter_test.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active
ws.auto_filter.ref = "Z100"
wb.save(filename)
```

Which moves it but does not unfilter the previous columns. The docs do not address this specifically and no search have been constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the ref attribute to None instead of moving it to another cell ?

Doing something like :

```
ws.auto_filter.ref = None
```

For me it did the trick without creating corruption in the saved file.